# Kunena forum. Setting special rank to a new user using custom plugin

Tags: php, joomla, kunena

everybody!
Could you please help me with the following problem.

Kunena 4.0.1. I have created several special user ranks. Some users have a permission to create new users. The task is to set rank of the new user differ to the default value but one of the special ranks.
I've tried to do it using a custom plugin related to the "onUserAfterSave" event. But it didn't work. What I’m doing wrong?

```
 function onUserAfterSave ($user, $isnew) 
  {

  if ($isnew)
    {
    $NewKUser = KunenaFactory::getUser(intval($user['id']));
    $NewKUser->rank['rank_id'] = 11;                
    $NewKUser->save(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please give full details. What kind of plugin you made e.g system plugin. kunena plugin etc? Also What class name you have given? it will help in debugging your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply! It's a user plugin. class plgUsersetraion extends JPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
function onUserAfterSave ($user, $isnew) {
   if ($isnew) {
    /*Current user rank*/
    $SelfUser = KunenaUserHelper::getMyself();
    $SelfUserRank = $SelfUser->getRank(0, false);
     /*If current user has custom rank...*/
    if ($SelfUserRank->rank_id >=11) {
        /*Setting new user's rank equal to the current user's rank*/
        $NewKUser = KunenaUser::getInstance(intval($user['id']), false);
    $NewKUser->rank = $SelfUserRank->rank_id;
    $NewKUser->save();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I got another solution, a one liner code but you need to edit existing plugin. So when a user registers in joomla, then it will be automatically assigned a rank.

For that you need to edit the kunena system plugin, which you can find at `plugins->system->kunena`.
if you open `kunena.php` you will find a function

```
public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg){
....
....
if ($isnew && intval($user ['id']))
        {
            $kuser = KunenaFactory::getUser(intval($user ['id']));
            $kuser->save();
        }
```

Change it or modify it by adding a single line `$kuser->rank`

```
public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg){
    ....
    ....
if ($isnew && intval($user ['id']))
        {
            $kuser = KunenaFactory::getUser(intval($user ['id']));
            $kuser->rank=11; // The rank which you want
            $kuser->save();
        }
```

Also its better to create a copy of that plugin before editing.